# Python environment set up issue

Tags: python, 3d, slicers

I am facing an issue while installing some packages in python also for MONAI label, Guess its an issue with the environment, This error message is shown before I open slicer app(DICOM viewer) Can anyone help me to resolve this(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlebJ.png)
I was trying to install MONAI label for 3d slicer